# Best way to create shops for Minecraft 1.7.2 Bukkit/Spigot server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-spigot

I'm running a Spigot server on a Raspberry Pi as a project and because of the obvious RAM limitations I have to turn off the Nether.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to set up a simple shop where players can turn in Iron, Gold, Redstone, Diamonds, etc. for "cash" or whatever and then use that to purchase things that they can't get (Nether related) and things that they can use for projects, but don't want to gather (eg. need lots of Iron, but *really* don't want to go mining).

I found [BossShop](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/bossshop/), which works with my 1.7.2 server, but I'm not sure exactly how to set it up. Do I need a separate economy plugin, because it appears that for the shop to work I do, and I cannot find any economy plugins that work with 1.7.2.

I have found [PlayerPoints](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/playerpoints/) and that works for 1.7.2, could I make BossShop work with just PlayerPoints?

If there isn't a way to set up an economy/shops using BossShop, are there any other plugins that work with 1.7.2?

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that you're able to host a **bukkit server** with just **512MB RAM** is *really* impressive.

Comment: @chipperyman573 It's actually a Spigot server, which is much lighter than default Bukkit. However, it wasn't going to be a public server, just a project for fun and to help me learn me learn my way around Raspbian/Bukkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that PlayerPoints works with BossShop, as it states here: [image]

There isn't a BEST shop plugin, while BossShop currently is one of the really good ones.
PlayerPoints is kind of like an economy plugin anyways.

Comment: Ah, you again :) Yes. I did read that and know that PlayerPoints work, but would BossShop work *just* with PlayerPoints? It would probably have to do with the plugin.yml file if so, correct?

Comment: Yes, me again :P Why would you think BossShop *wouldn't* work with PlayerPoints? You would need to use the java program that adds the items for you and set the price to points.

Comment: I don't think it wouldn't work, just was wondering how I would do it?

Comment: Just set the price to points and BossShop would take care of it :D Have a nice day. :P